# Escaping braces in pagedown/markdown when using MathJax

Tags: python, django, markdown, mezzanine, escaping

I'm used to a few hacks when using MathJax code in my pagedown to stop some characters being interpreted as special instructions (e.g. sometimes escaping underscores), but I can't seem to get `\left{` to work (`\left[` and `\left(` do). Escaping the brace doesn't work... what can I do instead?

I'm using pagedown in a Mezzanine project on Django/Python 3.